# See the Angular 6 click bindings in the developer console while in dev mode?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, dom, angular6

Assume I have a button with the following attributes:

```
<button>
    class="button"
    (click)="doStuff()"
    [ngClass]="{'stuff': selected}">
  Push me
 </button>
```

If I go to the console while running the app in development more, I only get a list of ng-reflect attributes that refer to my added attributes.

Question is: why don't I also see the (click) binding i just added?

Answer (score 3):

Because your code is **Typescript** code, and when you want to look at it into your browser, it's **Javascript** code.

When you write

```
<button>
    class="button"
    (click)="doStuff()"
    [ngClass]="{'stuff': selected}">
  Push me
</button>
```

This piece of HTML is actually translated in a string, that is used in the javascript code.

The compiler then search for `(click)`, and replace this code with `ng-reflect="doStuff()"` (this might not be true, but this is the idea).

It then binds an event with `button.addEventListener('click', () => {...})`, append the replaced string to the template, and your button then accepts click events.

This is an idea of how Angular works. If you want to know **exactly** how it does that, you can look at their source code.

But bottom line is : `(click)` isn't valid JS on a HTML tag, it works because of the compiled code the framework provides when you build your application.

Comment: the problem for me is  - for debugging purposes - i'd like to see exactly that ng-reflect='doStuff' or something like that that tells me I've added SOME event to that node. Sometimes I don't want to go back in the code to confirm that I've indeed added a (click) listener to that element

Comment: Well sorry but you can't, or more precisely I don't how you can if it's possible. Besides, as a developer, looking at your code to see what you did wrong shouldn't be an issue ...

Comment: it's more of an inconvenience; sometimes you don't want to break the flow while you're there in the browser looking at the DOM

Comment: The asker obviously asked about viewing the click event in the console for convenience and a quicker development experience (in the same manner you can see an ng-click, ng-if in AngularJs). He didn't ask how Angular works internally... Unfortunately, the Angular team made a poor choice to make debugging for developers much harder.